# Swift - Can't Reach SCNMorpher Target by Name

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm building a small animation app using SceneKit. I have a 3D model in an `.scn` file that has 6 SCNMorpher targets (namely blendShapes). They are all attributes of a node called `dinoNode`.

I can list the array of targets of the node simply by printing them to the console line.
`print(dinoNode.morpher?.targets)`

What I need to do now is to set a certain weight to one of the morpher's targets:

```
dinoNode.morpher?.setWeight(jawOpenQ, forTargetNamed: "jawOpenMesh")
```

For some reason this approach doesn't work. It appears XCode can't find a target named "`jawOpenMesh`". It is, however, listed in the array of targets at index 4 and I can easily do it this way:

```
dinoNode.morpher?.setWeight(jawOpenQ, forTargetAt: 4)
```

This works, but when there are 30-40 morpher targets it gets really confusing to reach them by their index. Would anybody know why **reaching the target by it's name** doesn't work for me?

P.S. When I try to reach the target by its name, it doesn't work, but doesn't throw any kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify key name from .scnassets just like below screen shot

[image: Morph key name is "Key"]

```
 @IBOutlet weak var scnView: SCNView!
var mainNode : SCNNode!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let scne = SCNScene(named: "scene.scnassets/ColladaTest_New.scn")

    self.scnView.scene = scne

    mainNode = self.getNodeByName(name: "CylinderWithSameGeometryAndMorpher")


    self.perform(#selector(self.performMorph), with: nil, afterDelay: 2.0)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc func performMorph()  {
     mainNode.morpher?.setWeight(1.5, forTargetNamed: "Key")
    //mainNode.morpher?.setWeight(1.5, forTargetAt: 0)
}

func getNodeByName(name:String) -> SCNNode {

   let node =  self.scnView.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: name, recursively: false)
    return node!
}
```

o/p will be as below [image: result morph]

make sure as key you don't have like below image (no name of key )

[image]

so in short you must have key name and you must spell it right in **forTargetNamed** parameter

that should work perfectly just like in above case :)